# How do I see other players' levels?

Tags: dead-island

Is there a way to see the level of the players who join my game or whom I join the game of? I feel like there was only ever one person who could tell what level I was, but I didn't get the chance to ask them how they knew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the level of other players, look at the PLAYERS tab of the character menu.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't, not directly.

However, if you turned off local monster scaling, you can tell approximately what level the host is based on the enemy levels, because the monsters will be scaled to the host.

Comment: Good insight. I've done that, but I never registered that consciously as a method. I only ever play in other people's games though, so if there really isn't a way, I can only guess that they guessed my level by presuming I was at the level cap.